# Report Viewer X Dapper

Tags: c#, reportviewer, dapper

I'm feeding a `ReportDataSource` with a query using Dapper.
However, I have an empty report, even with an `IEnumerable` loaded data.
When you spend a `Datatable` works.

How do I pass data from a query using Dapper for `ReportViewer`?

```
this.reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear(); 
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 

dt = CN.Query(Sql, param);

Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource rprtDTSource = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource(dt.TableName, dt); 
this.reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rprtDTSource); 
this.reportViewer.RefreshReport(); –
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like Dapper now [supports](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/issues/detail?id=156) the DataTable...

From the [test](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/master/Tests/Tests.cs):

```
public void ExecuteReader()
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(connection.ExecuteReader("select 3 as [three], 4 as [four]"));
    dt.Columns.Count.IsEqualTo(2);
    dt.Columns[0].ColumnName.IsEqualTo("three");
    dt.Columns[1].ColumnName.IsEqualTo("four");
    dt.Rows.Count.IsEqualTo(1);
    ((int)dt.Rows[0][0]).IsEqualTo(3);
    ((int)dt.Rows[0][1]).IsEqualTo(4);
}
```

Also [now](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/issues/detail?id=176) [supported](http://blog.marcgravell.com/2014/07/dapper-gets-type-handlers-and-learns.html) is using a DataTable as a TableValueParameter:

```
public void DataTableParameters()
{
    try { connection.Execute("drop proc #DataTableParameters"); } catch { }
    try { connection.Execute("drop table #DataTableParameters"); } catch { }
    try { connection.Execute("drop type MyTVPType"); } catch { }
    connection.Execute("create type MyTVPType as table (id int)");
    connection.Execute("create proc #DataTableParameters @ids MyTVPType readonly as select count(1) from @ids");

    var table = new DataTable { Columns = { { "id", typeof(int) } }, Rows = { { 1 }, { 2 }, { 3 } } };

    int count = connection.Query<int>("#DataTableParameters", new { ids = table.AsTableValuedParameter() }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).First();
    count.IsEqualTo(3);

    count = connection.Query<int>("select count(1) from @ids", new { ids = table.AsTableValuedParameter("MyTVPType") }).First();
    count.IsEqualTo(3);

    try
    {
        connection.Query<int>("select count(1) from @ids", new { ids = table.AsTableValuedParameter() }).First();
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.Message.Equals("The table type parameter 'ids' must have a valid type name.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As I could not find another way to feed my ReportViewer to a query Dapper.Query then downloaded the source and added the code below.

```
    #region CODTEC SISTEMAS
    /// <summary>
    /// Return a typed list of objects, reader is closed after the call
    /// </summary>
    public static DataTable Query(this IDbConnection cnn, string sql, object param, IDbTransaction transaction, int? commandTimeout, CommandType? commandType)
    {
        var identity = new Identity(sql, commandType, cnn, typeof(DapperRow), param == null ? null : param.GetType(), null);
        var info = GetCacheInfo(identity);

        IDbCommand cmd = null;
        IDataReader reader = null;

        bool wasClosed = cnn.State == ConnectionState.Closed;
        try
        {
            cmd = SetupCommand(cnn, transaction, sql, info.ParamReader, param, commandTimeout, commandType);

            if (wasClosed) cnn.Open();
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(wasClosed ? CommandBehavior.CloseConnection : CommandBehavior.Default);
            wasClosed = false; // *if* the connection was closed and we got this far, then we now have a reader
            // with the CloseConnection flag, so the reader will deal with the connection; we
            // still need something in the "finally" to ensure that broken SQL still results
            // in the connection closing itself

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(reader);


            // happy path; close the reader cleanly - no
            // need for "Cancel" etc
            reader.Dispose();
            reader = null;

            return dt;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (reader != null)
            {
                if (!reader.IsClosed) try { cmd.Cancel(); }
                    catch { /* don't spoil the existing exception */ }
                reader.Dispose();
            }
            if (wasClosed) cnn.Close();
            if (cmd != null) cmd.Dispose();
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: I know the post is old but you downloaded dapper source and added this method ; Is that correct ?

Comment: Thats such an overkill if he did. @Ken

Answer (score 1):

**To Get the DataTable from SqliteDB using Dapper.**

1. Pass the query such as "select*from table" inside the method.
2. list is formed, by executing query.
3. Then serialize the object into Json and then deserialize the Json
   into the DataTable.

   ```
   public DataTable method(string query)
   {
      string connection = @"Data Source= C:\User\DBFolder\sampleDB.db;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;";

      using (IDbConnection dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection(connection))
       {
           dbConnection.Open();
           var output1 = dbConnection.Query(query).ToList();
           dbConnection.Close();
           var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(output1);
           DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, (typeof(DataTable)));
           return dt;
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how Dapper works, but a datatable is binded like this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataColumn dc = dt.Columns.Add();
dc.ColumnName = "DataColumn1";
dc = dt.Columns.Add();

dc.ColumnName = "DataColumn2";
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Frank", 32 });
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1_DataTable1", dt));
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

and since I am using C#, I bind data sources like this:

```
this.bindingSource1.DataSource = getListMethod(); // this method/property returns a list of objects
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("Point", (this.bindingSource1)));
//Point is the datatable name in my Dataset.xsd file
```

Comment: With DataTable with no problems. However, the type returned by Dapper does not. I can not give it up once the routine parameters is very complex.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25871192/107625), here is my minimal Dapper extension to query SQL Server for a `DataTable` and optionally pass query parameters:

```cs
public static class DapperExtensions
{
    public static async Task<DataTable> QueryDataTable(
        string connectionString, 
        string sql, 
        object? param = null)
    {
        await using var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        await con.OpenAsync();

        var table = new DataTable();
        table.Load(await con.ExecuteReaderAsync(sql, param));

        return table;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```cs
var table = await QueryDataTable(
    "Server=myServer;Database=myDb;User Id=myUser;Password=myPw", 
    "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE ID > @id", 
    new { id = 5 });
```

Another example:

```cs
var table = await QueryDataTable(
    "Server=myServer;Database=myDb;User Id=myUser;Password=myPw", 
    "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE IsLocked = 0");
```

You might want to change `SqlConnection` to another database type like e.g. `NpgsqlConnection` for PostgreSQL.

---

To query only for a single `DataRow`, the Dapper extension class could be enhanced like this:

```cs
public static async Task<DataRow?> QueryDataRow(
    string connectionString, 
    string sql, 
    object? param = null)
{
    var table = await QueryDataTable(connectionString, sql, param);
    return table.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

And to finish this chain, although it makes no sense at all in the Dapper context, to query for a single value, the Dapper extension class could also contain this method:

```cs
public static async Task<object?> QueryValue(
    string connectionString, 
    string sql, 
    object? param = null)
{
    var row = await QueryDataRow(connectionString, sql, param);
    var result = row?[0];
    return result == DBNull.Value ? null : result;
}
```

Additionally, the `QueryValue` could also get a generic overload:

```cs
public static async Task<T?> QueryValue<T>(
    string connectionString, 
    string sql, 
    object? param = null)
{
    var value = await QueryValue(connectionString, sql, param);
    return value == null ? default : (T)value;
}
```